# Класс кучи (максимумов\минимумов) в .net

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите, есть ли класс кучи (максимумов\минимумов) в `.net (С#)`?

Comment: Вы об [этом](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0_%28%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%29)? Не слыхал о такой структуре данных в BCL, ищите сторонние компоненты или попробуйте реализовать сами.

Comment: Например, вот: http://stackoverflow.com/q/102398/276994

Comment: Есть интерфейс ISet<T>, который предоставляет интерфейс для множества, если ты их имеешь ввиду http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd412081.aspx. А вот реализация этого интерфейса в виде контейнера SortedSet<T> http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd412070.aspx.